# SSH exited without connecting to server in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh

I am trying to connect to the servers and cd into each directory. But when I tried to SSH into the first server which is **server1**, the error it gave me was

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

This is the config file and bash script below:

getPatches.cfg

```
SERVERLIST="server1;server2"
USERNAME=bob
DIRECTORY=/net/bob
```

bash script

```
#!/bin/sh

CFGFILE=getPatches.cfg

if ! [ -f $CFGFILE ] ; then
   echo "ERROR: $CFGFILE configuration file is missing"
   exit 1
fi
# READ $CFGFILE
. $CFGFILE
servers=$SERVERLIST
user=$USERNAME
directory=$DIRECTORY

#Tokenize ServerList
while IFS=';' read -ra ADDR; do
        for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
                ssh $user@$i
                AccessIntoDirectory="cd $directory"
                export AccessIntoDirectory
                ssh -q $i $AccessIntoDirectory
        done
done <<< "$servers"
```

I've generated a SSH public key and what this script should do is to SSH into the server and cd into the directory that I want, but it exited instead and did not SSH into the server. Any help would be great!

Comment: how do you handle passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to use ssh command without using the console(tty) is to add -t -t option.

```
ssh -t -t $user@$i
```

Answer (score 1):

At first check the line

```
ssh $user@$i
```

It does not supply a command, so your script tries to start an interactive shell on the remote host. That's where you get the error from.

Secondly I'd like to check if you accidently used backticks `` instead of ticks '' or double quotes "" in the line with

```
`AccessIntoDirectory=`cd $directory`
```

which would falsely run the 'cd' command and assign it's output to the variable.

Comment: Opps I am sorry, cd $direcotory is supposed to be in double quotes. I tried SSH bob@server1, it is connected successfully to server1. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve ssh $user@$i?

Comment: a plain `ssh user@server` starts a new ssh process, connects to the external host, tries to start an interactive login-shell for `user` (which fails) and exits back to your local host.  Then it sets `$AccessIntoDirectory` to 'whatever' on your local host. Done that, it starts a 'cd whatever' as remote command in s anew shell and immediatley returns.